# Fatal error, no such file or directory ( eclipse android )

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, cocos2d-x, fatal-error

I'm developing a cocos2d-x project, as its universal it works on android and iOS.

I recently added text to speech functionality using flite. In xcode all I do to use flite, is drag in the folder of the headers and c files into my xcode project, and then I can include its headers and use it. No problems there.

However in eclipse I can't get the compiler to see the files, and it keeps bombing out with the fatal error I mentioned. Specifically: fatal error: flite.h no such file or directory.

I've tried to include the folder in the includes section of eclipse under C/C++ general but no luck. I think this may have something to do with my android.mk file, guidance on how to set this up for this purpose would be greatly appreciated. On a side note, my project is set up so that my .cpp and .h files exist elsewhere on my computer and not in my actual project. Likewise for my flite source files. (I did try add them to my project however, out of desperation but the compiler still couldn't find them)

Thanks for your time.

PS: How does one refer to flite, is it a library/framework etc?

**Edit**
I tried to modify my Android.mk file, to locate the flite headers. My additions are indicated below

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)



include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := game_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libgame

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
               ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
               ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp \
               ../../Classes/CCLabelTTFExtension.cpp \
               ../../Classes/menuScene.cpp \
               ../../Classes/text_Parse.cpp \
               ../../Classes/FileTS.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes/ 
#my addition
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/flite/


dirs := $(shell /flite  -type d)

cfilestemp1 := $(shell find /src -type d)
cfilestemp2 := $(shell find $(cfilestemp1) -name *.c)
cfilestemp3 := $(sort $(cfilestemp2))
cfiles := $(subst $(LOCAL_PATH)/,,$(cfilestemp3))

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
           $(cfiles)
#end my addition

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static cocosdenshion_static     cocos_extension_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android) \
$(call import-module,cocos2dx) \
$(call import-module,extensions) 


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
```

This got me closer, well, gave me different errors. Now the compiler complains of undefined references in my FileTS.cpp file, the file which is using flite in my project. (Note: My flite headers and source files are now added to my project in the jni folder)

Comment: Is your flite lib a compiled version or you want to compile it from source? the easiest way is to put all the source code into your Classes folder and list the cpp files in LOCAL_SRC_FILES like mainScene.cpp  . this will make sure your library get build into your game object files.

Comment: If the flite is a compiled version then it will be hard to tell because we don't know which processor it aimed to. if the lib is compiled for non-arm processor then you probably cannot use it.

Comment: I'm aiming to compile it from source, but it includes quite a lot of .c files, I presume all of them would need manually listing

Comment: I guess you need to. you can list the .c files along those .cpp files including the correct path.

Comment: Thanks. To make things easier I used wildcard to list all the .c files automatically, and just listed all the individual header folders using local_c_includes. Submit an answer and i'll give you the bounty because it works now :)

Comment: Thanks~ It is always great time when you see something works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to put all the source code into your Classes folder and list the cpp files in LOCAL_SRC_FILES like mainScene.cpp . this will make sure your library get build into your game object files.

Comment: Can you provide more details on this please?

Comment: @Josh This answer might be out dated since it is aiming cocos2d-x 1.x. they might changed their structure on how to build from source.